# How can I substitute the value of one variable in a multivariate function?

Tags: python, python-2.7, sympy, evalf

Suppose, I have a function f(x,y)=x<sup>2</sup>+y<sup>2</sup>. Now, I would like to substitute `x=2`, keeping `y` symbolic. I tried with

```
f.evalf(subs={x:2})
```

But it is not substituting the value of x, and just giving me the original expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't resolve all the symbols, so you won't get an evaluation which is what `evalf` tries to do - it only works if it substitutes all the variables in your expression.

You can however use `subs` directly on your expression.

```
>>> from sympy import *

>>> x, y = symbols('x y')

>>> expr = x**2 + y**2

>>> expr.subs(x, 2)
y**2 + 4
```

And if needed, could subsequently call `evalf()`.